# Visual Studio 2010 list copy construct throwing C2664 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

**SOLVED: Restarted Visual Studio**

I'm working on a project for school involving the `STL` list. and getting this error with `xmemory`. I'm just trying to build the solution at this point, but`xmemory` is killing me

> Error  1   error C2664: 'GroceryStoreItem::GroceryStoreItem(GroceryStoreItem &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'GroceryStoreItem &'   d:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory  208

Here's my header

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
//
//*****************************************************************
//                     USER DEFINED DATA TYPES
//

class GroceryStoreItem
{
friend ostream & operator<< (ostream &out, const GroceryStoreItem &RHS);

public:
GroceryStoreItem();
GroceryStoreItem(string Name, double cost, string location);
GroceryStoreItem(GroceryStoreItem & GroceryStoreItemCCIn);
GroceryStoreItem & operator= (const GroceryStoreItem &RHS);
string ReturnItemName();
string ReturnLocation();
double ReturnCost();

private:
string ItemName;
string Location;
double Cost;
};
```

and the implementation

```
#include "Grocery_Item.h"

using namespace std;
//*****************************************************************
//                  Grocery Item Constructors
//*****************************************************************
GroceryStoreItem::GroceryStoreItem()
{
ItemName = "default";
Location = "aisle 1";
Cost = 0.0;
}

GroceryStoreItem::GroceryStoreItem(string InName, double InCost, string InLocation)
{
ItemName = InName;
Location = InLocation;
if(InCost >= 0.0f)
{
Cost = InCost;
}
else
{
Cost = 0.0f;
}

 }

 GroceryStoreItem::GroceryStoreItem(GroceryStoreItem & GroceryStoreItemCCIn)       //Copy Constructor
{
ItemName=GroceryStoreItemCCIn.ItemName;
Location=GroceryStoreItemCCIn.Location;
Cost=GroceryStoreItemCCIn.Cost;
}
```

edit
`xmemory` error in the last line of

```
    template<class _Other>
    void construct(pointer _Ptr, _Other&& _Val)
    {   // construct object at _Ptr with value _Val
    ::new ((void _FARQ *)_Ptr) _Ty(_STD forward<_Other>(_Val));
```

Comment: What line does this error come from? Post that part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I closed Visual Studio, started a new project and pasted my CPPs and Headers into the new project, and it compiled and worked. Not the ideal answer, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your copy constructor argument const

```
GroceryStoreItem::GroceryStoreItem(const GroceryStoreItem& GroceryStoreItemCCIn)
```

Also it's generally better to use initialisation not assignment in your copy constructor

```
GroceryStoreItem::GroceryStoreItem(const GroceryStoreItem& rhs) :
    ItemName(rhs.ItemName),
    Location(rhs.Location),
    Cost(rhs.Cost)
{
}
```

Finally (and this is the most important lesson of all) because you have done the right thing and used `std::string` internally in your class you don't actually need a copy constructor at all. The compiler generated default will do the right thing anyway. So I would actually delete your copy constructor, this will also fix the error.

Same argument for your assignment operator, delete that too.

Comment: I've tried removing the copy constructor and am still getting the error

Comment: I tried compiling the code you've posted. No error for me (same compiler too). It's probably when you are compiling the code that uses GroceryStoreItem that the error occurs. Could you post that code?

Comment: I saved the modified code to a txt file and restarted visual studio, started a new project and it works now. gotta love it. Thanks for the help!